# How to shape train and test data for sklearn svm

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, svm

I m using the pandas library to extract the data and use it to feed svc classifier like this :

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import pandas as pd

train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
X_train = train['FunctionalWordPercent']
Y_train  = train['openness']

test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
X_test = test['FunctionalWordPercent']
Y_test  = test['openness']

clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train) 
SVC(kernel="linear", c=1.0)

print(clf.score(X_test,Y_test))
```

But I keep getting the following error :

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using a single column (feature) for X. For this code to work, you need to do this:

```
X_train = train['FunctionalWordPercent']
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1,1)


X_test = test['FunctionalWordPercent']
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1,1)
```